# HTML element positioning

Tags: html, css

I was trying to recreate a magazine cover using HTML and CSS but I've hit a rock.

Whenever, I try to rotate the textarea and align it leftmost, I get only the top corner getting cut, but I would like to cut it more.

This is the CSS I use for my element :

```
textarea {
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  height: 740px;
  width: 520px;
}
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3P9u/1/)
And here's [the cover](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lvOioZOLp9M/T6Vo1d3UyiI/AAAAAAAAGCE/SxtRj6HaTdU/s1600/Cover.png)

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more explicit as to what your problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Header positionning**

Change the `z-index` of your element to put it on top of the other elements, e.g.

```
z-index : 10;
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3P9u/2/)

**Textarea positionning**

You want to cut more of the textarea. It's really as simple as putting a

```
margin-left: -100px;
```

Comment: I need to position the textarea as it is in the image.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get the question, I thought you were talking about the header. Use `margin-left` with negative values on the textarea ?

Comment: Yes, that does it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Rotate()` rotates its contents, keeping its `width` and `height`.

You need to add extra `padding` or `margin` to show all the contents.